# How to write sub-query with group by in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sql

I am new in learning Magento. I need to create query like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ARIDNR IN (
SELECT ARIDNR
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ARIDNR
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

How to write this using collection method or any other method?

Answer (score 0):

**Create Model that link with table YourTable.**

```
$Collection = Mage::getModel('module/model')->getCollection();
$Collection->getSelect()->group('ARIDNR')->having('COUNT(*) > ?', 1);
```

Comment: thank you so much,for answer but this query return single record with group by clause.i need to fetch  all data with same id in group.

Comment: so must be use sub query for that as a show in question

Comment: remove group by

Comment: Please accept my answer & help full for other